# First duplicate in a vector

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following code that finds first duplicate in a vector of integers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int find_duplicate(const vector<int> &v)
{
    unordered_set<int> numbers;
    
    for(const auto num : v)
    {
        if (numbers.count(num) > 0)
        {
            return num;
        }
        else
        {
            numbers.insert(num);
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 6, 2};
    cout << find_duplicate(v);
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a more concise way of writing this using C++ std library algorithms?

find_duplicate should not modify the input vector nor make a copy of it.

Comment: `insert` returns a pair containing an interator and a bool; the bool tells you if the value was inserted or if it already existed. So you can use the bool to check for duplicates in your set, rather than doing a separate lookup via `count()`.

Comment: `insert()` on `unordered_set` returns a `std::pair<iterator, bool>` that tells you whether the insert was successful (i.e. whether no equivalent value was in the set before). You can just `if (!numbers.insert(num).second) return num;`

Comment: Using a set, effectively makes a copy of your vector. Clearly it's not an exact copy as obviously they are different data structures, but the underlying data values would be copies.

Say you have a vector of 10 ints, and none of them are duplicates. At the end of find_duplicate, you will have a set that has copies of the same ints.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Right, I can simplify that. But I what I am looking for is some smart one line solution using std lib algorithm, if that exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard library is built around iterators rather than indices. If you change your `find_duplicate` function to return an iterator, this can be concisely written as:

```cpp
auto find_duplicate(const vector<int> &v)
{
    unordered_set<int> numbers;

    return std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [&](int num) { return !numbers.insert(num).second; });
}
```

Note that `unordered_set<T>::insert` returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`, where the `bool` is true if we inserted a new element and false if the element was already in the set.

Whether this is good code is debatable. A common expectation when reading code using standard algorithms is that the lambda doesn't mutate things, and this lambda mutates `numbers` as part of its process.

---

If you want to keep the `find_duplicate` function's signature the same, you can still do that:

```cpp
int find_duplicate(const vector<int> &v)
{
    unordered_set<int> numbers;

    auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [&](int num) { return !numbers.insert(num).second; });

    return it == v.end() ? -1 : *it;
}
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to put the `unordered_set` into the predicate: `[numbers = std::unordered_set<int>()](int num) mutable { ... }`: it doesn't have any business outside the predicate. A potential caveat is that the standard library doesn't make any promise on how the predicate gets copied...

Comment: @DietmarKühl Indeed, that's why I tend to leave it outside the lambda and capture by reference. I'm not fond of `mutable` lambdas.